# Python list of dictionaries join list com

Tags: python-3.x

```
products = [
    {
        "discontinued": 0,
        "lead_time_days": 4,
        "product_category": "Toy",
        "product_description": "Pull out a bock without crashing the stack ...",
        "product_id": 101,
        "product_name": "Jenga Classic Game",
        "reorder_level": 50,
        "unit_price": 14.99
    },
    {
        "discontinued": 0,
        "lead_time_days": 4,
        "product_category": "Wireless Phone Accessory",
        "product_description": "Display: 2.5 inches Camera: 2 MP Talk Time: 4.5 hours Weight: 3.3 ounces",
        "product_id": 102,
        "product_name": "AT&T Z431 GoPhone (AT&T)",
        "reorder_level": 14,
        "unit_price": 49.99
    },
    {
        "discontinued": 1,
        "lead_time_days": 4,
        "product_category": "Wireless Phone Accessory",
        "product_description": "Display: 4.5-inches Camera: 5-MP Input: Touchscreen OS: Android",
        "product_id": 103,
        "product_name": "AT&T Z998 LTE Android Go Phone (AT&T Prepaid)",
        "reorder_level": 29,
        "unit_price": 159.99
    },
    {
        "discontinued": 1,
        "lead_time_days": 4,
        "product_category": "Personal Computers",
        "product_description": "8 inch Display (1920x1200) ...",
        "product_id": 104,
        "product_name": "NVIDIA SHIELD Tablet (WiFi)",
        "reorder_level": 10,
        "unit_price": 299.0
    }
]
```

Python list of dictionaries,  how to print their product_category together with their product_description formatted as "product_category - product_description"  like: product_category - product_description which discontinued == 1 ?

For the format, using the `join`, like `print('- '.join(str1))`
But I don't know how to link them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass through the list with a simple [list comprehension](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python) (with an `if` clause to account for `discontinued`), and do the `join` per element in the list, like this:

```
print_messages = [' - '.join([product['product_name'], product['product_description']]) 
                  for product in products if product['discontinued']]

for message in print_messages:
    print(message)
```

Comment: @bowenyang if the answer helped you, please mark it as "accepted" (with the little green "v" sign). This way, others will know that the question is answered.